# ASPxGridView -Custom Controls in DetailRow

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I try to have custom controls in a DevExpress grids detail row. When ever a row is expanded I would like to load data into those custom controls based on the Masters Key.
I am using the detailrow expended method.

```
protected void grid_DetailRowExpandedChanged(object sender, ASPxGridViewDetailRowEventArgs e)
    if (e.Expanded)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(grd.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "ID"));
        ...
    }
```

The problem is I don't know how to access the custom controls in the expended detail row. I don't see any Row or Items properties on the grid, which would have been with a FindControl().
Any one got a clue on how to get the detail row or even a  row object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void grid_DetailRowExpandedChanged(object sender, ASPxGridViewDetailRowEventArgs e)   
if (e.Expanded)   
{   
    YourControlType yourcontrol = (YourControlType)grid.FindDetailRowTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, "YourControlName")
}
```